# Button icon dissapears onclick

Tags: javascript, button

I'm working with a button, that stores a number of likes on a post.
Code:

```
<button id="likebtn" type="button" 
        class="btn btn-sml btn-danger" style="width:70px;">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> </i> 
    <?php echo $post_likes; ?>
```

[image: Like button unclicked]

The problem comes, when I click the button - the like icon disappears.
It appears back when I refresh the page.
Code.

```
let likebtn = document.querySelector('#likebtn');
likebtn.addEventListener('click', likes_function => {
        //increace likes
        likebtn.value = <?php echo $post_likes?> + 1;
        likebtn.innerHTML = <?php echo $post_likes?> + 1;
                                
        document.getElementById("likebtn").disabled = true;
                        
        document.getElementById("likebtn").style.opacity=0.5;
                                                                                    
         }                                         
 });
```

[image: ike button clicked]

How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You must add the `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> </i>` to the `likebtn.innerHTML = <?php echo $post_likes?> + 1;`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `innerHTML` is replacing the entire contents inside button including the icon. You can wrap likes in a nested element and only replace the contents of that:

```
<button id="likebtn" type="button" class="btn btn-sml btn-danger" style="width:70px">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> 
  <span class="likes"><?php echo $post_likes; ?></span>
</button>

// ....

const likeBtn = document.querySelector('#likebtn');
const likeBtnLabel = likeBtn.querySelector('.likes')

likeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Increase likes.
  likeBtn.value = <?php echo $post_likes?> + 1;
  likeBtnLabel.innerText = <?php echo $post_likes?> + 1;
                          
  likeBtn.disabled = true;         
  likeBtn.style.opacity = 0.5;
});
```

P.S. `likes_function` does not name your function, instead you named the first argument of the click function "likes_function", which is a [mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) object

Also note I changed `innerHTML` to `innerText` for security reasons since you only need to change text and not html.